# Taking ED-E to the scrap yard

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I had this quest before I repaired ED-E, but I also went to the scrapyard and spoke to the lady before getting ED-E as a companion.

Now when I chat to her she doesn't have any dialog options regarding the bot. I assumed she should have a dialog option to tinker with it perhaps and end the quest.

When I select the quest and show location the marker remains pointing to the scrap yard. Am I missing something obvious or is this a game bug? Is there a console command to reset the NPC so that I haven't met her, in order to seek a new dialog option?

I'm particular about finishing quests in my log you see ;)

Comment: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/ED-E_My_Love - Didn't know about the wiki but it's answered my question !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the only purpose to taking ED-E to the scrap yard is to unlock the first Enclave voice-message.  By the time I picked ED-E up in the game, I had actually killed the old lady (Gibson, I think her name is), in order to get her dog's brain for Rex - so talking to her was impossible.

Instead, while ED-E was following me around, I accidentally triggered the message while walking through/talking to characters at the B.O.S. base.  Five (in game) days later, I triggered the 2nd message at HELIOS ONE.

Details on how to do this are available here: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/ED-E_My_Love